# How to use inmemory data base for Junits in Play 2.2

Tags: frameworks, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am working on play 2.2 for my application. In my application.conf, I have specified the connection properties as below.
    db.testdb.driver=org.h2.Driver
    db.testdb.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
    db.testdb.user=xxxxx
    db.testdb.password=xxxx
    And When I try to access the h2 db in my Jnuit , I am getting connection "testdb" undefined error.

```
Junit:

    FakeApplication app = Helpers.fakeApplication(Helpers.inMemoryDatabase("testdb"));
    Helpers.start(app);


Please help me to connect h2 db from my Junit.
Thanks in adv.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use default setting for h2 db:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver#
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play#"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""
```